# How do I make it go to the home page?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using Django and after login, I redirect to the main page. If there are still tokens in the session, I don't want to go to the login page. How can I do that ?

```
    class LoginPageView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'login.html'

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.session['token']:
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                return redirect('home')
```

My Urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('login/', views.LoginPageView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^sign-in/$', views.sign_in, name='sign-in')
]
```

I wrote code like this, but it doesn't work.

> KeyError at /login/
>   'token'

Comment: `if 'token' in request.session: return redirect('login')`

Comment: views.LoginPageView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: you need to write the else part too. btw `else` can be skipped, but you need to write the second `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. `request.session['token']` will raise a `KeyError` if there is no token. That is the error you are seeing. Use `request.session.get('token')` instead, it return `None` if there is no `token`.
2. Ignoring 1., your logic is flipped, currently it would redirect to `login` if there is a token and redirect to `home` if there isn't one.
3. 2. would cause a redirect loop and the user would never see your `login.html` template

What you want to do instead, is redirect to `home` if there is a token and render the `login.html` template if there isn't.

```
class LoginPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.session.get('token'):
            return redirect('home')
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.session.get('token'):  # trivial change, makes it safe for KeyError
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
```

Apart from the obvious, there may be logic flaws in the code too.

- I don't see any token validation.
- If the user has a token, he or she gets redirected to /login?